# Get reference to a Particle System created in Scene Editor

Tags: swift, reference, scenekit, ios10, particle-system

I've created a particle system in the Scene Editor (not the particle Editor), and it's named "particles" (this is the default name).

Back in the ViewController, I'm attempting to get a reference to this particle system and change some properties of it.

But I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "particles", inDirectory: "")
        particleSystem?.isAffectedByGravity = true
```

I know it's possible to set gravity on within the Scene Editor, but I'm simply using this as a test to see if the reference to the Particle System is working. It's not.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

ADDITIONAL EFFORTS:

As per Rickster's suggestion, trying this:

```
 let particleSystems = scene.particleSystems
    let myParticleSystem = particleSystems?[0]
    myParticleSystem?.isAffectedByGravity = true
    print(particleSystems)
```

This has now this problem:

[image]

My thinking (faulty as it is) was that the array's 0 location would have the only particle system I have in this scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of the scene I got:

[image: SCNParticleSystem instance assigned to SCNNOde]

And the code to get a reference to the particle system assigned to the particles SCNNode instance:

### In Swift 2.3 (and earlier)

```
 let particlesNode:SCNNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("particles", recursively: true)!
 let particleSystem:SCNParticleSystem = (particlesNode.particleSystems?.first)!
```

### In Swift 3.0

```
 let particlesNode:SCNNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "particles", recursively: true)!
 let particleSystem:SCNParticleSystem = (particlesNode.particleSystems?.first)!
```

### Alternative Array Index Syntax

```
 let particleSystem:SCNParticleSystem = (particlesNode.particleSystems?[0])!
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That funky (?.)! or (?[])! syntax is doing my head in. Optionals are sent to test us. Or maybe just me.

Comment: Apparently I have to wait 20hrs before I can award you the bounty. I tried to do it immediately, your answer is spot on, and worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad it worked for you. And thanks for the bounty ;-)

Comment: If there was more than one particle system attached to this node, do you happen to know if there's a way to know which one you'd be getting. Or how the sorting is done so (let's say) the third one down the list in the Scene Editor is the one I want? Is it sequential as per the editor? Some kind of naming system work from Scene Editor to code?

Comment: I don't see a way to add more than one particle system to a given node in the SceneKit Editor. But maybe there is. What I see is that everytime your drop a particle system, it creates a node for it and assigns it to the node. However, I see the option of adding more than one in code: [addparticlesystem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1523123-addparticlesystem) and [removeparticlesystem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1524014-removeparticlesystem). And then the order is sequential in the particlesystems array property.

Comment: I think I had a false idea of what's going on. The name in the hierarchy list is not the name of the particleSystem, it's the name of the node that has a particle system attached to it. In your image (in the answer above) I was long thinking "particles" was the name of the particle system attached to the root. But it's actually a node attached to the root, and the particle system is not named, nor visible in the Scene Editor hierarchy as a named object, only its contents in the Scene Editor.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing this up. I was originally thinking scene was also a node, the root node. But it seems the rootNode of a scene is the first node, not the scene itself. Hence my first efforts at scene.particleSystems not returning anything. Amongst several other reasons. Baffling.

Comment: That's correct. The Identity name in the Node inspector is that of the node. I usually add the first node as an empty and call it root. Then I add the other nodes to it.

Comment: This means I can duplicate an item (node) in the Scene Editor's Node Inspector, and it's given the exact same name as the Node being duplicated. Why would that be possible? I can't think of a single good reason to have it act like that. Surely this should be more like Photoshop layers, in that any duplicated Node's copy should be named "node copy 01" etc

Comment: Yes. The default node name is always the same, "particles" as opposed to "particles1", "particles2" etc...

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs for that initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnparticlesystem/1522772-init) suggest, it's for loading particle systems that are in their own files. When you make a particle system in the scene editor, the particle system isn't its own file — it's part of the scene file you're making.

To find it... well, first you have to load the `SCNScene` object that file represents. Assuming you've done that already, you'll need one of two ways to access the particle system depending on how you defined it in the editor:

- If the particle system is attached to a node — the straightforward way to position it in the scene — you can use the scene's [`rootNode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscene/1524029-rootnode) property to get at the scene contents, then use methods like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407951-childnode) to find the node containing the particle system using the name you assigned it in the editor. (You did give it a name in the editor, right? If not, go do that... or worst case, there's always [this method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407982-childnodes) that lets you search for nodes based on any test you can code.)
- If not, use the scene's [`particleSystems`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscene/1522787-particlesystems) property to find all systems that aren't attached to nodes.

Comment: I'm really struggling with the apple docs. What does this look like when it's actually used? var particleSystems: [SCNParticleSystem]? { get }

Comment: btw, yes, not a child. I've added particle systems at the top of the hierarchy, they're not children of anything else in the scene. Just using the base SceneKit template and dragging them in from the object maker pool on the bottom right. Then picking and dragging them up out of the hierarchy where they default to being.

Comment: I'd previously tried the "find the childNode with name" approach, and got a reference to it, but it wasn't a particle system, was coming back as an SKNode and I couldn't figure out how to cast this back/down to a particle system.

Comment: dragging objects from the Object Library will always create a `SCNNode` to hold that object. Everything you see in the scene graph view on the left of the editor is a node. Never a node attribute like a light, camera or particle system.

Comment: Great. So how do I get a reference to a Particle System I've created in this manner?